# python redistimeseries Timestamp cannot be older than the latest timestamp in the time series

Tags: python, redis, time-series, redistimeseries

I am trying to use the Python redistimeseries package (RedisLabs v0.8.0)
Python Redis package (RedisLabs) v3.5.3

However when I perform a TS.ADD - it always returns the error

```
redis.exceptions.ResponseError: TSDB: Timestamp cannot be older than the latest timestamp in the time series
```

no matter what timestamp I give it. I can take the same timestamp value, and do the same ADD in redis-cli on the same time-series without any issue.

To make sure existing records are not the issue I create a new time-series, so no keys/values/timestamps exist. same result.

Example:

```
REDIS-CLI 127.0.0.1:6379> TS.CREATE FAN02.RUNTIME RETENTION 604800 LABELS eq_type FANS location SITE1

REDIS-CLI 127.0.0.1:6379>  TS.ADD FAN04.RUNTIME 1591720015 39
(integer) 1591720015
```

works fine.

But if I do the same in Python (using a new empty time-series), using a current timestamp I get the error;

```
>>> int(time.time())
1591720015

import redistimeseries.client
rts = redistimeseries.client.Client(host='x.x.x.x', port=6379)
rts.add('FAN04.RUNTIME', int(time.time()), newval)

>>> stacktrace
  File "C:/.../putdata.py", line 105, in main
    rts.add('FAN04.RUNTIME', int(time.time()), newval)
  File "C:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\redistimeseries\client.py", line 186,     in add
    return self.execute_command(self.ADD_CMD, *params)
  File "C:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\redis\client.py", line 901, in execute_command
    return self.parse_response(conn, command_name, **options)
  File "C:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\redis\client.py", line 915, in     parse_response
    response = connection.read_response()
  File "C:\...\venv\lib\site-packages\redis\connection.py", line 756, in read_response
    raise response

redis.exceptions.ResponseError: TSDB: Timestamp cannot be older than the latest timestamp in the time series
```

Not sure what is going on or what I am doing incorrectly, I am having a hard time finding documentation or examples for the Python package that would highlight my error or lack of understanding.

Any ideas ?

I am using Python 3.7, Redis 3.5.3, Redis TimeSeries 0.8.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python's `time.time()` returns the current time as a floating point value of the seconds, whereas RedisTimeSeries expects millisecond resolution... Try:

```
rts.add('FAN04.RUNTIME', int(time.time() * 1000), newval)
```

Or use `datetime`'s `now()` or similar...

Comment: int(time.time() * 1000)
1591803454935

and

round(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.now().timetuple()) * 1e3)
1591803560000   

 - produce the same error. still trying to find a working example where someone is doing this correctly.....

Comment: Actually, your answer is working - I failed to notice the code is running/looping so fast that it generates the same timestamp value !